# How to ensure ordered delivery of messages on a session enabled queue/subscription when dead lettering happens in Azure Service Bus

Tags: session, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, dead-letter, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am working on building an integration project which involves the usage of Azure Service Bus Topic subscriptions and an Azure Function app subscribing to the topic. My essential requirement is to ensure the updates related to a user(which can happen at different time intervals in a day) must be delivered in the same order of occurrence and perform parallel processing of the messages.

For Example, consider below updates:

1. User1 made a payment
2. User2 updated profile
3. User2 made a payment
4. User1 changed address
5. User1 reported a dispute on the payment
6. User2 reported a dispute on the payment

These three updates per User1 and User2 may happen at different times of the day but must be sent to the subscribing Function app in the same order. In the example, a dispute on a payment can not be sent before the payment update.

To achieve this I have chosen to implement [Message Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions) on Service Bus. First I enable the session on the Service Bus queue/topic and set the user-id as session-id while publishing a message.

I know I can implement PeekLock behavior and client-side retries to recover from transient failures. Suppose, because of an issue (could be client-side or max delivery count exhausted) the message is moved to a dead lettering queue in Service Bus. I can create another Azure function to retry the dead-lettered messages.

But how do I ensure the messages are delivered in the same sequence if one message is dead-lettered?
Are there any best practices to ensure I do auto retry of dead-lettered messages and at the same time deliver updates in the same order they are published into the queue?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**Note:** I did not find a similar question in stack overflow, hence posted this question. I find retry of dead-lettered queues but not in the case of session-enabled queues/topics.

Comment: What happens if a message from the sequence is dead-lettered? Can your process continue, or does it have to be aborted? And is there anything in the messages that would indicate they've arrived with a gap?

Comment: Process can continue processing other User's updates. But, the subsequent messages of a dead-lettered message (per session) must not be processed until the dead-lettered message is not processed. User ID is used as session ID to identify the messages related to user are processed in sequence.

Comment: How do you identify "subsequent messages of the DLQ-ed message"? Also, ASB will insist to process the session messages regardless if one or more messages has failed. Are you OK with dead-lettering those subsequent messages? I.e. how do you see your requirement materialized given the ASB behavior?

Comment: One possibility I am seeing is to dead-letter subsequent messages and process them in order from dead-letter queue. For this to achieve, when function app receives the message, it must peek dead-letter queue and verify if there is a message with same session id in dead-letter queue, if the message exists then move the message to dead-letter queue instead of processing it. A separate function can be created to process the messages in dead-letter queue.

Comment: But you're still not solving the problem as processing from DLQ can also fail on one of the messages.